# react-native integrate local website into react-native page

Tags: node.js, react-native, webview

For a project I need to implement a website (html,css,js,threejs, several pages that get loaded over jquery/ajax into the main part of the website) into a page of a react-native app. It has to work without internet connection. My first take was to load the .html file into a webView component, but its not working because it wont fetch the data over `file///`, only over `https//`. I also tried with code bundling like webpack, htmlwebpack and inliner but none of these bundled files have been working so far. When it comes to the offical **React Native WebView Guide** it says :

> Note: This is currently not working as discussed in #428 and #518.
> Possible workarounds include bundling all assets with webpack or
> similar, or running a local webserver.

but my main question now is: Are there alternatives to the webview component or plugins that have been designed for that usecase? Solutions for the webview component are also very welcome.

This is my page right now in react-native

```
import React from "react";
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview'

export default function myPageScreen() {
  return (
    <WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{uri:'file:///android_asset/index.html'}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
  />
  );
}
```